# Using Map-Reduce to Return A Modified Array of Strings

Tags: javascript

I am learning map & reduce, but am having a hard time understanding how to utilize these methods to tackle problems.

For example,

Create a function that takes a number and returns an array of strings containing the number cut off at each digit.

420 should return ["4", "42", "420"]

My old Approach:

```
function createArrayOfTiers(num) {
    var numArr = num.toString().split('');
    var output = [];
    for(var i = numArr.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        output.unshift(numArr.join('');
        numArr.pop();
        }
    return output;
    }
```

Attempt to use map-reduce combination:

```
function createArrayOfTiers(num) {
    var numArr = num.toString().split('');
    return numArr.map(function(element) {
    var newElement = numArr.reduce(function(acc, val) {
        return acc + val;
    });
    numArr.splice(element, 1);
    return newElement;
    });
}
```

Comment: Your indentation could use some work as its quite confusing right now. Just think of `map` as something that takes a handler, passes in every element and stores the returned value into a new array, while `reduce` takes a value and a handler, passes in the array item into the handler together with the value, and only returns the value the handler returns. So... `[1,2,3].reduce((v,n) => v + n, 0) === 6` and `[1,2,3].map(v => v + 4) === [5,6,7]`... I think what you are trying to do with a string is not really the use for these methods...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used two loops, but apparently it can be done just with one.

```js
function n(num) {
  let res = (""+num).split('').map((_,i) => (""+num).slice(0, i+1));
  return res;
}

console.log(n(420));
console.log(n(13579));
```

One-liner.

```js
const n = num => (""+num).split('').map((_,i) => (""+num).slice(0, i+1));

console.log(n(420));
console.log(n(13579));
```

Comment: What does _ mean in the context of .map(_, i)?

Comment: @Reign `_` sign means an unused argument. The first passed argument stands for current element and the second one stands for the index of current element. In this particular case, we need only the index argument. I could replace `_` with any character, but `_` is used to let know other programmers that this argument wasn't used anywhere inside the function. More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

I don't think these are good uses-cases of `map` or `reduce`, but here goes :

```js
var numArr = [4,2,0];
var result = numArr.map(e => numArr.join(''))  // now ["420", "420", "420"]
                   .map((arr, i) => arr.substring(0, i+1)) // now ["4", "42", "420"]
console.log(result);
```

We first replace every element of the array by the whole (unmodified) array joined into a string, then substring each of these strings based on their position in the outer array.

There's a reduction hidden in there, although not using `reduce` : `join` reduces `[4, 2, 0]` to `"420"`.

---

> I am learning map & reduce, but am having a hard time understanding how to utilize these methods to tackle problems.

Mapping associates to each value of the source array a new value provided by a mapping function : if you have an `[x, y, z]` array, a mapping function `f(x)=x+1`, the result of mapping the array with the function will be `[x+1, y+1, z+1]`.

I believe reduction was meant to "reduce" an array to a primitive type, although I might be mistaken. If you have an `[x, y, z]` array and reduce it with the addition operation, the result will be `x+y+z`.

Answer (score 0):

As others noted, that this problem doesn't seem to be the best use case of the `map` and `reduce` functions.

1. `map` function provides the `element`, `index` and `array` information in the parameters. Making use of these you can iterate on the elements you need to apply the `reduce` function.
2. Statement `var arrayToIterate = arr.slice(0,i+1);` helps to achieve the above mentioned array to iterate.

**Complete Code:**

```js
function createArrayOfTiers(num) {
    var numArr = num.toString().split('');
    return numArr.map(function(element, i, arr) {
 var arrayToIterate = arr.slice(0,i+1);
        var newElement = arrayToIterate.reduce(function(acc, val) {
        return acc + val;
    },"");
    return newElement;
    });
}

var result = createArrayOfTiers(420);
console.log(result);
```